# Syntax error at last if isset and echo within a table

Tags: php

Please help diagnose my syntax error at line noted here as `**?></th>**`, but of course in my real code it is `?></th>`. All of my variables as defined properly before this code but not shown here. Thank you for any assistance.

```
<table width="600" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><h1><?php
if (isset($_POST['dogTitle']))
{
            echo  $_POST['dogTitle'];

    }
?></h1></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['dogDescription']))
{
            echo  $_POST['dogDescription'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['vet']))
{
            echo  $_POST['vet'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['vetDescription']))
{
            echo  $_POST['vetDescription'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['apply_to_email']))
{
            echo  $_POST['apply_to_email'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['apply_to_url']))
{
            echo  $_POST['apply_to_url'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['vetCity']))
{
            echo  $_POST['vetCity'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['vetState']))
{
            echo  $_POST['vetState'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['vetZip']))
{
            echo  $_POST['vetZip'];
            ?></th>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php
    if (isset($_POST['FtPTCHrly']))
{
            echo  $_POST['FtPTCHrly'];
            **?></th>**
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You have a bunch of open brackets but no close brackets

Comment: I think the syntax error is that you missed `}` for many `if`s?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to complete If statement after this  snippet
So, Instead of this code.

```
<th scope="row"><?php
if (isset($_POST['dogDescription']))
{
        echo  $_POST['dogDescription'];
        ?></th>
```

Replace it With this.

```
<th scope="row"><?php
if (isset($_POST['dogDescription']))
{
        echo  $_POST['dogDescription'];
 } // You missed this
 ?></th>
```

At so many places in your code this is the error so, correct it.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot believe I did not catch that. All set now.